# Associate attributes with products in opencart to generate xml file

Tags: php, xml, opencart

The past couple of hours I am trying to generate an xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mywebstore>
   <created_at>2010-04-08 12:32</created_at>
   <products>
      <product>
          <id>322233</id>
          <name><![CDATA[MadBiker 600 Black Polarized]]></name>
          <link><![CDATA[http://www.mywebstore.gr/product/322233]]></link>
          <image><![CDATA[http://www.mywebstore.gr/product/322233.jpg]]></image>
          <category id="23"><![CDATA[Sports > Extreme Sports]]></category>
          <price_with_vat>322.33</price_with_vat>
          <manufacturer><![CDATA[SuperGlasses]]></manufacturer>
          <description><![CDATA[This is the description.....]]></description>
          <weight>350</weight>
          <mpn>ZHD332</mpn>
          <instock>N</instock>
          <availability>Pre-order</availability>
      </product>
      <product>
       ...
      </product>
   </products>
</mywebstore>
```

from opencart.

I have written this piece of code

```
<?php
class ControllerFeedSkroutzXml extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->language->load('feed/skroutz_xml');

        if ($this->config->get('skroutz_xml_status')) {
            $output  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
            $output .= '<mywebstore>';
            $output .= '<created_at>' . date('Y-m-d H:i') . '</created_at>';
            $output .= '<products>';

            $this->load->model('catalog/product');

            $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();

            foreach ($products as $product) {

                $attribute_groups = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes($product['product_id']);
                //print_r($attribute_groups);
                if (!empty($attribute_groups)) {
                    foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) {
                        if (!empty($attribute_group)) {
                            foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) {
                                $attribute = array_filter($attribute);
                                if (!empty($attribute)) {
                                    // [attribute_id] => 13, Color
                                    if ($attribute['attribute_id'] == 13 && $attribute['text'] != '') {
                                        $attribute_color = $attribute['text'];
                                    }
                                    // [attribute_id] => 16, Lens Technology
                                    if ($attribute['attribute_id'] == 16 && $attribute['text'] != '') {
                                        $attribute_lens_technology = $attribute['text'];
                                    }
                                }
                            }                           
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ($product['special']) {
                    $final_price = number_format((float)$product['special'], 2, '.', '');
                } else {
                    $final_price = number_format((float)$product['price'], 2, '.', '');
                }
                if ($product['quantity'] > 0) {
                    $instock = $this->language->get('instock_Y');
                } else {
                    $instock = $this->language->get('instock_N');
                }

                $output .= '<product>';
                $output .= '<id>' . $product['product_id'] . '</id>';
                $output .= '<name><![CDATA[' . $this->language->get('category_name') . ' ' . $product['name'] . ' ' . $attribute_color . ' ' . $attribute_lens_technology . ']]></name>';
                $output .= '<link><![CDATA[' . $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']) . ']]></link>';
                $output .= '<image><![CDATA['. HTTP_IMAGE . $product['image'] . ']]></image>';
                $output .= '<category id="' . $product['manufacturer_id'] . '"><![CDATA[ ' . $this->language->get('category_name') . ' > ' . $product['manufacturer'] . ' ]]></category>';
                $output .= '<price_with_vat>' . $final_price . '</price_with_vat>';
                $output .= '<manufacturer><![CDATA[' . $product['manufacturer'] . ']]></manufacturer>';
                $output .= '<description><![CDATA[' . $product['meta_description'] . ']]></description>';
                $output .= '<instock>' . $instock . '</instock>';
                $output .= '<availability>' . $product['stock_status'] . '</availability>';
                $output .= '</product>';
            }

            $output .= '</products>';
            $output .= '</mywebstore>';

            $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/xml');
            $this->response->setOutput($output);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But the block of code that generates the attributes it doesn't work as expected.
A lot of my products don't have attributes (at least not yet), so what I want to accomplish is to show attributes right next to the name of the product

**Example**
**Name:** MadBiker 600
**Attribute - Color:** Black
**Attribute - Lens Technology :** Polarized

All together `<name>MadBiker 600 Black Polarized</name>`

**Only if a product has attributes!**
The above php code generates the `<name>MadBiker 600 Black Polarized</name>` to all empty of attributes products until it finds the next product with an attribute!

Could someone please point out where is the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't resetting the `$attribute_lens_technology` and `$attribute_color` with each iteration of the foreach. You need to reset these after the foreach loop definition

New foreach loop:

```
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $attribute_lens_technology = false;
            $attribute_color = false;

            $attribute_groups = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes($product['product_id']);
            //print_r($attribute_groups);
            if (!empty($attribute_groups)) {
                foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) {
                    if (!empty($attribute_group)) {
                        foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) {
                            $attribute = array_filter($attribute);
                            if (!empty($attribute)) {
                                // [attribute_id] => 13, Color
                                if ($attribute['attribute_id'] == 13 && $attribute['text'] != '') {
                                    $attribute_color = $attribute['text'];
                                }
                                // [attribute_id] => 16, Lens Technology
                                if ($attribute['attribute_id'] == 16 && $attribute['text'] != '') {
                                    $attribute_lens_technology = $attribute['text'];
                                }
                            }
                        }                           
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($attribute_lens_technology === false || $attribute_color === false) {
                // Code here such as continue; if you want to skip products without both attributes
            }

            if ($product['special']) {
                $final_price = number_format((float)$product['special'], 2, '.', '');
            } else {
                $final_price = number_format((float)$product['price'], 2, '.', '');
            }
            if ($product['quantity'] > 0) {
                $instock = $this->language->get('instock_Y');
            } else {
                $instock = $this->language->get('instock_N');
            }

            $output .= '<product>';
            $output .= '<id>' . $product['product_id'] . '</id>';
            $output .= '<name><![CDATA[' . $this->language->get('category_name') . ' ' . $product['name'] . ' ' . $attribute_color . ' ' . $attribute_lens_technology . ']]></name>';
            $output .= '<link><![CDATA[' . $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']) . ']]></link>';
            $output .= '<image><![CDATA['. HTTP_IMAGE . $product['image'] . ']]></image>';
            $output .= '<category id="' . $product['manufacturer_id'] . '"><![CDATA[ ' . $this->language->get('category_name') . ' > ' . $product['manufacturer'] . ' ]]></category>';
            $output .= '<price_with_vat>' . $final_price . '</price_with_vat>';
            $output .= '<manufacturer><![CDATA[' . $product['manufacturer'] . ']]></manufacturer>';
            $output .= '<description><![CDATA[' . $product['meta_description'] . ']]></description>';
            $output .= '<instock>' . $instock . '</instock>';
            $output .= '<availability>' . $product['stock_status'] . '</availability>';
            $output .= '</product>';
        }
```

Comment: why is that required, these will be set only once in each `foreach product` loop and there are used in that loop only

Comment: @ChetanPaliwal - Not all products have attributes, thus the if block starting `if (!empty($attribute_groups)) {` doesn't get executed, and so the values remain the same as they were on the last iteration

Comment: @ChetanPaliwal - It wasn't immediately obvious :-)

Comment: @JayGilford how could I check an empty array to avoid this trouble?

Comment: @kanenas.net - See the above edit. You can test it pretty simply

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to write an xml file using [simplexml](https://www.php.net/simplexml) than it is to manually try and output your own.

Nevertheless, here's a simple shorthand if statement to fix to your problem though (if attribute color is empty, it will append an empty string instead:

```
$output .= !empty($attribute_color) ? '<name><![CDATA[' . $this->language->get('category_name') . ' ' . $product['name'] . ' ' . $attribute_color . ' ' . $attribute_lens_technology . ']]></name>' : '';
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. It generates the same output like my code :(

Comment: right before this shorthand if statement, can you do exit(var_dump($attribute_color)); and paste the result?

Comment: string(51) "Μαύρο / Γκρι Ντεγκραντέ (528/11)".   
The attributes are in Greek.

Comment: I probably should have specified, the element with the attribute color you just pasted.. are you expecting it to not have that? Ultimately my guess is that attribute_color is still set on subsequent products, only out of not being unset. Perhaps at the bottom of your foreach loop (after </product) do unset($attribute_color); and then remove my exit statement I just gave you

Comment: The answer Jay just gave is essentially what I just said, he probably worded it better though :p

Comment: +1 you did give the answer pretty much the exact time I did :)